# Omitting 'is' in English sentences

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, difference, adverbs

Legs shaking, he walked up the hill

Chest heaving, he stopped for a rest

Why not, legs are shaking and chest is heaving?

Comment: For one thing, _are_ is present tense and _walked_ is past tense!

Comment: A short answer: Because the main clause of the sentence is "he walked up the hill" or "he stopped for a rest".  *Legs shaking* and *chest heaving* are phrases that describe something about the main clause.

Answer (score 4):

These are examples of what traditional grammar calls absolute phrases. Martha Kolln (*Understanding English Grammar*) explains them this way:

> **The absolute phrase** (also known as the *nominative absolute*) is a structure independent from the main sentence; in form the absolute phrase is
> a noun phrase that includes a postnoun modifier. The modifier is commonly an *-en* or *-ing* participle or participial phrase, but it can also be a
> prepositional phrase, an adjective phrase, or a noun phrase. The absolute
> phrase introduces an idea related to the sentence as a whole, not to any
> one of its parts:
>
> *Our car having developed engine trouble*, we stopped for the night
> at a roadside rest area.
>
> *The weather being warm and clear*, we decided to have a picnic.
>
> *Victory assured*, the fans stood and cheered during the last five
> minutes of the game.

If you were to add a conjugated form of **be** to your sentences, you would have to add a conjunction to avoid creating a comma splice:

> *Although* his legs were shaking, he walked up the hill.
>
> *Because* his chest was heaving, he stopped for a rest.

The subordinating conjunction is required because the rules of written English say that you must not have more than one independent clause in a single sentence (unless they are separated by strong punctuation, such as a semicolon).

You could also avoid the **be** verb by adding a preposition:

> *With* [his] legs shaking, he walked up the hill.
>
> *With* [his] chest heaving, he stopped for a rest.